# How to save []byte data in array list

Tags: go

#### Summarize the problem

I make some application that receive data from toggl api.
I try to save []byte response data in array list in Go to modify data later.
I want to know how to translate and store this response []byte json style data as array list.

#### Show some code

main.go

```golang
type togglData struct {
}

func GetTogglReports() []byte {
    //some code

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return data
}

func makeSurveyText() {
    // I want to save []byte data GetTogglReports() in array list here.
    var togglData []togglData
}
```

data is like this:

```
 {
    "total_grand":36004000,
    "total_billable":14400000,
    "total_currencies":[{"currency":"EUR","amount":40}],
    "data": [
      {
        "id":193009951,
        "title":{"project":"Toggl Development","client":null},
        "time":14400000,
        "total_currencies":[{"currency":"EUR","amount":0}],
        "items":[
          {
            "title":{"time_entry":"Hard work"},
            "time":14400000,
            "cur":"EUR",
            "sum":0,
            "rate":50
          }
        ]
      },{
        "id":null,
        "title":{"project":null,"client":null},
        "time":7204000,
        "total_currencies":[],
        "items":[
          {
            "title":{"time_entry":"No title yet"},
            "time":1000,
            "cur":"EUR",
            "sum":0,
            "rate":50
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step one convert your JSON into a go struct.  To do this I always use an online converter like https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    TotalGrand      int `json:"total_grand"`
    TotalBillable   int `json:"total_billable"`
    TotalCurrencies []struct {
        Currency string `json:"currency"`
        Amount   int    `json:"amount"`
    } `json:"total_currencies"`
    Data []struct {
        ID    int `json:"id"`
        Title struct {
            Project string      `json:"project"`
            Client  interface{} `json:"client"`
        } `json:"title"`
        Time            int `json:"time"`
        TotalCurrencies []struct {
            Currency string `json:"currency"`
            Amount   int    `json:"amount"`
        } `json:"total_currencies"`
        Items []struct {
            Title struct {
                TimeEntry string `json:"time_entry"`
            } `json:"title"`
            Time int    `json:"time"`
            Cur  string `json:"cur"`
            Sum  int    `json:"sum"`
            Rate int    `json:"rate"`
        } `json:"items"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
```

Then

- read the json file into a byte array ie, using `http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)` , `client.Do(req)` and `byte_array,err:=ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`
- with `make` or `new` create an instance of the struct
- process the byte array into the struct instance `json.Unmarshal(byte_array, &instance_of_struct)`

You will then have a struct containing the data from the JSON